# How to select some string in 1 column database table

Tags: database, oracle

I have 1 record `value = ABC2015000001`.

How to select that record and show `000001` only?

That means I want select value 6 digits from behind.

Comment: Please tag your `DBMS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Substring` can be used to do this;

**Oracle**

```
select SUBSTR('ABC2015000001', length('ABC2015000001') - 5, 6) from DUAL
```

**sql server**

```
select SUBSTRING('ABC2015000001', len('ABC2015000001') - 5, 6)
select right('ABC2015000001', 6)
```

**mysql**

```
select SUBSTR('ABC2015000001', length('ABC2015000001') - 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Praveen's syntax for Oracle works, but you can do it in a slightly simpler way, without the `length()` call or the second substring-length argument. [`substr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm) allows a negative position argument:

> - If position is 0, then it is treated as 1.
> - If position is positive, then Oracle Database counts from the beginning of char to find the first character.
> - If position is negative, then Oracle counts backward from the end of char.
> - If substring_length is omitted, then Oracle returns all characters to the end of char. If substring_length is less than 1, then Oracle returns null.

Combining the last two points, you can pass -6 as the position to say you want to start 6 characters from the end, and omit the second argument so it gets the remainder of the string:

```
SQL> select substr('ABC2015000001', -6) from dual;

SUBSTR
------
000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Which database type do you use?

Generally in almost all databases there is `Substring(parameters)` function.